# How to hide the grdiview gridlines using jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

IAm using the grdiview ,in which iam using the print option,problem i want to remove the gridlines using javascript or jquery, i dont want it in the codebehind or in the gridview property,when the printdiv function is called the grdilines should disappear.grd is the asp gridview name.kindly provide some suggestions

```
function printDiv(divID) {



$("<%=grd.ClientID %> tr").css({ 'border-color': 'White', 'border-width': '0px' });
$("<%=grd.ClientID %>").attr("border", "0");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just do:

```
$("<%=grd.ClientID %>").hide();
```

The above should do.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to examine the gridview to determine where the styling is set.  Likely it's on the td and th as well.  You're on the right track, but, perhaps do:

```
$("<%=grd.ClientID %> tr, <%=grd.ClientID %> td, <%=grd.ClientID %> th").css({ 'border-color': 'White', 'border-width': '0px' });
```